# GSON, json в enum. Задать значение по умолчанию

Tags: json, retrofit, gson, enum

С помощью `retrofit` получаю с сервера `json`. Например такой:

```
["3","23","3","1","2","11","4"]
```

Далее эта радость десериализуется в поток `Enum`-ов . Нюанс в том, что особый интерес вызывают только числа до, допустим, 4. Все, что больше, тоже интересно, но только в качестве факта присутствия.

`Enum` такой(Kotlin, но это считайте, что Java):

```
enum class AccidentDamage(val text: String, val code: Int) {
    @SerializedName("1") WITHOUT("жив, цел, орёл!", 1),
    @SerializedName("2") LIGHT("вроде цел", 2),
    @SerializedName("3") HEAVY("вроде жив", 3),
    @SerializedName("4") LETHAL("летальный", 4),
    UNKNOWN("неизвестно", 255);
}
```

То есть мне надо, что бы 1..4 подставились правильно, а все остальное вернулось как UNKNOWN. По данному `json` должен сформироваться такой поток `Enum`-ов:

HEAVY,**UNKNOWN**,HEAVY,WITHOUT,LIGHT,**UNKNOWN**,LETHAL

Возможно ли это сделать без написания адаптеров?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По умолчанию никак.

Реализовать подобное поведение можно с помощью [самописного десериализатора.](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html)

```
private class AccidentDamageDeserializer 
    implements JsonDeserializer<AccidentDamage> {

  @Override
  public AccidentDamage deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type,
        JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    String damage = json.getAsString();
    switch(damage){
        case "1" : return AccidentDamage.WITHOUT;
        case "2" : return AccidentDamage.LIGHT;
        case "3" : return AccidentDamage.HEAVY;
        case "4" : return AccidentDamage.LETHAL;
        default  : return AccidentDamage.UNKNOWN;
    }
}
```

Использовать так

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(AccidentDamage.class, new AccidentDamageDeserializer () );
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
```